# What is zero times zero

Tags: elementary-number-theory, field-theory

What is zero zeros?
What are no nothings?
From a mathematical point of view it would be my thing, but none of us are educated that much in math, so I am curious to hear an expert opinion.

Comment: Is this at all helpful or convincing?

$0 * 0 = (1 - 1) * 0 = 1 * 0 - 1 * 0 = 0 - 0 = 0$.

Comment: Well $0\cdot 0 = 0$. The empty product, however, is 1, i.e. $\prod_{i\in\emptyset}x_i = 1$.

Comment: You have nothing. You increase your nothing, nothing times. That is, you do nothing. Nothing changes. You are still left with nothing.

Comment: "but none of us are educated that much in math" But isn't arithmetic taught in elementary school?  Wasn't $0\times 0=0$ taught to you?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes, we were taught that, but the question I asked was more of a curiosity thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It entirely depends on what you mean by 'zero'. Usually in algebra the zero element of some set, with some 'addition' operation has the property that $a + 0 = a$ where $a$ can be any element of your set. That is, we use addition to define what zero is. If your set of things (affectionately denoted $G$) also has a 'multiplication' operation, and that operation behaves like multiplication on $\mathbb R$ then it can be shown that $a \cdot 0 = 0$ for all $a$ in $G$. Since $0$ is also in $G$ it follows that $0 \cdot 0 = 0$. An example of an algebraic structure where this is all true is a field ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29)).

So, the way I rationalise this, no lots of nothing is still nothing, because you are counting the amount of nothing you have. But a cleaner way to seeing this is to realise where $0$ came from in the first place, and derive the fact that $0 \cdot 0 = 0$ using axioms.